# How do I update output to the command line without printing to a new line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, command-line-interface

I'd like to do things like make updating progress bars and realtime counts of files processed, but I don't want it to span hundreds of line.

Specifically, I'm processing about 6500 emails and it takes several minutes. I'd like to print how many have been processed without it taking 6500 lines.

I've seen some solutions in Python 2, but I haven't been able to figure it out in Python 3.

Comment: `print(stuff, end='')`

Comment: I also need it to replace the existing output, not write "1 file(s) processed2 file(s) processed3 file(s) processed4 file(s) processed5 file(s) processed6 file(s) processed..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should print it using `sys.stdout` with carriage return `'\r'`. Here you have an example:

```
import time
import sys

for i in range(100):
    sys.stdout.write(str(i+1) + '%\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Try it out!

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately, the output wasn't what I was expecting. This is what I got:

1%
2%
3%
4%
5%
6%
7%
8%
9%
10%
11%
12%
13%
14%
15%
16%
17%
18%
19%
20%
21%
22%
23%
24%
25%
26%
27%
28%
29%
30%
31%
32%
33%
34%
35%
36%
37%
38%
39%
40%
41%
42%
43%
44%
45%
46%
47%
48%
49%
50%
51%
52%
53%
54%
55%
56%
57%
58%
59%
60%
61%
62%
63%
64%
65%
66%
67%
68%
69%
70%
71%
72%
73%
74%
75%
76%
77%
78%
79%
80%
81%
82%
83%
84%
85%
86%
87%
88%
89%
90%
91%
92%
93%
94%
95%
96%
97%
98%
99%
100%

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to use the grey quote boxes yet, but that's exactly what I got, all of the numbers from 1-100 without newlines. They printed sequentially, but without overwriting the existing value.

Comment: @CodyBrock It should work! [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMS1VZamxVeUFhYVU) you can run my sample snippet! Try it!

Comment: IDLE. Is that the problem?

Comment: Do not forget to store the output of `write`! If you don't it will print garbage in you nice count: `dummy = sys.stdout.write(...)`

Comment: @CodyBrock yep, that won't work on IDLE (see [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35768165/carriage-return-not-working-in-idle)). You should write a python file and execute it from terminal or command promt

Comment: Perfect! That's the solution for sure. Thank you @CarlesMitjans