# Python treating carriage return as newline character. What can I do instead?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, newline, carriage-return

I want to write a code which prints `Loading`, and then erases that and prints `Loading.`, erases that too and prints `Loading..` and so on. So I tried using `\r`, but python interprets it as `\n`. Is there a charcter I can use instead of `\r`?

I've tried using `\b` instead, but Python doesn't recognize it, either. For example, if I print `qwerty\buiop`, it just prints `qwertyuiop`.

This is the code I tried, using carriage return:

```
import time
for y in range (5):
        for i in range (4):
                print("Loading","."*i, end="\r")
                time.sleep(0.5)
```

However, instead of printing how I want it to, it prints like

Loading

Loading .

Loading ..

Loading ...

in different lines.

How do I solve this problem? Is there a different character I can use?

I'm using IDLE and MacOS.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think IDLE attempts to interpret control characters like that. Try a different shell.

Answer (score 1):

I know you probably know an answer by now, but for people still looking for one:

Try using an empty end, while using \r at the beginning of each print to overwrite the previous one.

```
import time
for i in range (4):
  print("\rLoading","."*i, end ="")
  time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running your program in terminal.

Different shells interpret the \r character in different ways. A lot of them will write out each print as a separate output rather than one ongoing stream. Terminal should interpret it the way you are thinking

Comment: I tried to run this code on Terminal, but it threw a SyntaxError, even though it doesn't throw any errors in IDLE. Also, I've never used anything except IDLE to run my programs, so I wanna go for Terminal as a last resort. Is there no way this program will work on IDLE? I don't have to necessarily use `\r` if something else works instead.

Comment: I'll see if I can find an idle example, but I've tried to do a similar thing before in a different interpreter without much luck... Even using some more elaborate code. Give me a sec :)

Comment: Try something like this maybe @PlatinumTheHitgirl? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35768165/carriage-return-not-working-in-idle

Comment: I did try, but it doesn't work. I guess I'll have to change shells. Anyways, thanks for helping out!

Comment: Good luck! I tried a bunch of things too and eventually switched, you'll have better luck doing it that way since most programs are eventually run on terminal or bash @PlatinumTheHitgirl