# Carriage return (\r) works different on python idle vs VS Code

Tags: python, python-idle

```
import time

for i in range(10):
    print(f"Progress: {i}/10", end='\r')
    time.sleep(1)
```

When I run this code in VS Code it works as expected by showing "Progress" in place going from 1 to 10, but when running it on the idle it displays the following:

```
Progress: 0/10Progress: 1/10Progress: 2/10Progress: 3/10Progress: 4/10Progress: 5/10Progress: 6/10Progress: 7/10Progress: 8/10Progress: 9/10
```

What's the reason for this?

I tried some online idle sites like W3Schools and they output the same thing like the picture.

Comment: @s3dev `\r` is intentional, I presume, to show the progress updates in place rather than on separate lines.

Comment: correct, I want it displayed on the same place

Comment: The meaning of '\r' is not as well-defined and some think.  On Macs, at least in the past, it meant the same as '\n' on Unix and Windows.  Even if 'return to the beginning of this line', does it erase the existing line or not.  Note that on typewriters and printing terminals, which predated glass terminals and terminal emulator  programs, there was no erasure.  If existing text is left, do new characters insert, replace, or overwrite (as on typewriters)?  Note that replace/overwrite depend on having fixed pitch chars.  IDLE devs chose to display what is output and not choose an interpretation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that IDLE still doesn't support most control characters such as \r etc (I ran this on Python IDLE 3.12.2 )  link to the original psot
[Carriage Return not working in IDLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35768165/carriage-return-not-working-in-idle)

Comment: so the output in the vs code is the correct one right?

Comment: yes, by setting end='\r', we're specifying that instead of a newline,  the cursor should return to the beginning of the line (carriage return), effectively overwriting the previous line.